# Close Ext.Window from child html

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJS.

This is my window definition :

```
this.dialog = new Ext.Window({
title : "About us",
layout  : 'anchor',
modal   : true,
autoEl : {
        tag : "iframe",
        id: "myframe",
        src : "../editor/actorseditor.html",
        height: 500,
        width : 600
} });   
this.dialog.show();
```

I want to close my dialog window from "actorseditor.html".

How to achieve this. Also the opened window is not having close button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set window to `closeable:true` in the config.

Comment: @cclerville Done.. No affect

Comment: Ok I don't know if you noticed my error but its `closable:true` and not `closeable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if the html page in your iFrame is from the same application as your parent page. Or at least the protocol, subdomain, domain and port are all the same.

You will need to expose a global function in your parent page that will be called by the JavaScript running in the child page (iframe).

In your child page you call:

```
 if (window.parent && window.parent.myGlobalFunction) {
       window.parent.myGlobalFunction('hello!');
  }
```

In your parent page you include the following global function (name it as you wish of course):

```
function myGlobalFunction(input){
        console.log('message received:'+input);
        MyApp.app.fireEvent('closeMyWindow',input);
    }
```

This assumes that you are using MVC and you created property 'app' and set it to 'this' in the application launch function. And that you have a controller that is listening for aplication wide event like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Qnum', {
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    init:function(){
        this.control({
            ...
        });
        //listen for app wide event fired by : MyApp.app.fireEvent('closeMyWindow',input);
        this.application.on({
            closeMyWindow: this.closeWindowItsDrafty,
            scope: this
        });
    },
    closeWindowItsDrafty:function(){
       //get reference to my window
       //call myWindow.close();
    }
```

Comment: I added close button in ExtJs window followed by adding a listener from where I fired the event for closing the window. Its workin fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that in actorseditor.html, you must have a button

In this button you can set this listener:

```
listeners : {
    click : function () {
         Ext.getCmp('yourdialogid').close();
    }
}
```

You also need to put an id to your dialog box.

Comment: @Chunk Birkin  My actorseditor.html is a simple html page with a script for loading the chart and two buttons namely add & cancel. where to add the listener

Comment: @Hermant Kumar. How else are you planing on closing the window from the inner page? You need a button or a link, you need an item to close it, there you put the listener

Comment: this will not work as JS running in IFrame is limited to the objects scoped within.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following inside your close button listener:

```
var parentDialogWindow = window.parent.Ext.cmp('ID_OF_DIALOG_WINDOW');
parentDialogWindow[parentDialogWindow.closeAction]();
```